# PHP function stops working when split into more functions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php function that builds a mysql query and then gets products from the database and then turns the database rows into php objects...

```
function queryDbForProducts($conn, $place) {

    $queryObject = buildSQLWhereClause($place);
    $query = $queryObject['query'];
    $queryParams = $queryObject['queryParams'];
    $queryParamTypes = $queryObject['queryParamTypes'];
    array_unshift($queryParams, $queryParamTypes);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), makeValuesReferenced($queryParams));
    $stmt->execute();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
        $parameters[] =& $row[$field->name];
    }

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_result'), $parameters);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            $x[$key] = $val;
        }
        //$results[] = $x;

        $product = array(
            "name" => $x['p_name'],
            "brand" => $x['brand'],
            "imagePath" => $x['image_path']
        );

        $shop = array(
            "name" => $x['s_name'],
            "country" => $x['country'],
            "province" => $x['province'],
            "city" => $x['city'],
            "suburb" => $x['suburb'],
            "street" => $x['street'],
            "streetNumber" => $x['streetNumber']
        );

        $productInformation = array(
            "product" => $product,
            "shop" => $shop
        );

        $allProducts[] = $productInformation;
    }
    return $allProducts;
}
```

I would like to refactor it into more functions but it always stops working when I try. For instance:

```
function parseResultsToPHPObjects($stmt, $parameters) {
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_result'), $parameters);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            $x[$key] = $val;
        }
        //$results[] = $x;

        $product = array(
            "name" => $x['p_name'],
            "brand" => $x['brand'],
            "imagePath" => $x['image_path']
        );

        $shop = array(
            "name" => $x['s_name'],
            "country" => $x['country'],
            "province" => $x['province'],
            "city" => $x['city'],
            "suburb" => $x['suburb'],
            "street" => $x['street'],
            "streetNumber" => $x['streetNumber']
        );

        $productInformation = array(
            "product" => $product,
            "shop" => $shop
        );

        $allProducts[] = $productInformation;
    }//********************** line 66 *******************************

    return $allProducts;
}

function queryDbForProducts($conn, $place) {

    $queryObject = buildSQLWhereClause($place);
    $query = $queryObject['query'];
    $queryParams = $queryObject['queryParams'];
    $queryParamTypes = $queryObject['queryParamTypes'];
    array_unshift($queryParams, $queryParamTypes);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), makeValuesReferenced($queryParams));
    $stmt->execute();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
        $parameters[] =& $row[$field->name];
    }
    return parseResultsToPHPObjects($stmt, $parameters);
}
```

Gives this error:

> 05-May-2016 21:16:41 Pacific/Auckland] PHP Parse error:  syntax error,
>   unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/the_vegan_repository/scripts/back_end/get_products.php
>   on line 66

Rows are returned from the database still, but they contain no information. Can this function be split up successfully?

Comment: @Apb It is commented in the code in the question :)

Comment: What preceeds this that function? That's only like 30-some lines to that point, so there are 30-some lines before presumably?

Comment: only this globally `if ($_POST["place"] && $_POST["categories"]) {
    require 'database_connection.php';
    $SqlQueryResult = queryDbForProducts($conn, $_POST["place"], $_POST["categories"]);
    $conn->close();
    echo json_encode($SqlQueryResult);
}`

Comment: Couldn't see a syntax error. Did you present to us the correct file? I would challenge the reported error against the code. Insert some blank lines. Does the line number in the error message changes? What happens if you remove the function entirely, or replace it with an empty dummy? Those a absolutely wild guesses, because your posted code appears to be correct.